# Insert different values per column at once

Tags: sql, postgresql

After adding a new column is it possible to insert values for that column using only one query?

**TABLE:**

```
id |  category   | level | new_column_name
---+-------------+-------+----------------
 1 | Character   |     3 |  
 2 | Character   |     2 |
 3 | Character   |     2 |
 4 | Character   |     5 |
```

I'd need to do something like

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
    (new_column_name)
VALUES
    ('foo'), -- value for new_column_name : row1
    ('bar'), -- value for new_column_name : row2
    ...
;
```

I already used a similar query using postgresql cli in order to insert values, but it fails becauase uses `null` for the unset column values, one of which (id) is PRIMARY_KEY, so it can't be NULL.

This is the error it logs:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, 1359).
```

**EDIT:**

What I'm doing is more an update than an insert, but what I would be able to do is to insert all the different values at once.

For instance, if possible, I would avoid doing this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET new_column_name = 'foo'
WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE table_name
SET new_column_name = 'bar',
WHERE id = 2;

--...
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to `update` instead of `insert` perhaps?

Comment: @sgeddes yes it's more an update, but I'd like to do it without having to use the where clause of the update command if possible. I forgot to add that in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VALUES` so as to construct an in-line table containing the values to be updated.:

```
UPDATE table_name AS v 
SET new_column_name = s.val
FROM (VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')) AS s(id, val)
WHERE v.id = s.id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0f912/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a huge `CASE`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET new_column_name
   = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'foo'
          WHEN id = 2 THEN 'bar'
     END;
```